# how to paginate divs with $.ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, handler

I've tried several ways to paginate divs wich came from ashx handlers, (ASPX Handlers), using AJAX (jQuery) technology. The handlers are in C#, .ashx files, but the returned data is in html.

But i can't complete. I would like to have an idea of the algorithem or some technologies that does this.

I've tried several solutions existent in this website, but all of them didn't worked for me.

I would like to paginate 8 divs for each page.

**example:**

```
    //Page 1
    <div class="productArea">
        <div class="product" id="one1"></div> ... <div class="product" id="eight1"></div>
    </div>
```

then paginate and pass to other page

```
    //Page 2
    <div class="productArea">
        <div class="product" id="one2"></div> ... <div class="product" id="eight2"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: How many rows in total are your retrieving?

Comment: there is not fixed, this is dynamic.

Comment: Ballpark then... between 8 and 15? between 200 and 600? 3000 and 8000?

Comment: You'll have duplicate ID's in your sample if both pages exist in the DOM at the same time

Comment: 500 and 800 rows not more

Comment: 500-800 is well into the range where creating the dom and hiding it will be less efficient than creating the pages on the fly, therefore i suggest creating each page as it is needed and displaying it.

Comment: your sugestion is to how many rows tops?

Comment: I would start doing it that way at 20 or more, but that's just my opinion. I find it cleaner to do it from the start that way i most cases anyway due to the way things tend to grow.

Comment: okey, but how can i do it?

Comment: What do you mean how can you do it.. you just do. write code that takes data and only shows 1 page at a time.

Comment: not that, the pagination of divs, i'll do that but i would like to see a solution for this problem.

Comment: I'm not going to do it for you. **You haven't presented us with a problem to solve.**

Comment: i didn't ask for a complete solution, but a way to do this, like how can i paginate divs, algorithem or technologies to do this

Comment: But you don't need an algorithm... You just keep track of what page you are on, and show the data for that page accordingly.

Comment: If there are only that few, then you can use something like DataTables plugin